# HomeBrew link error

Tags: homebrew

Hello i have a problem with HomeBrew . I issue a command :

```
Ahmet-MacBook:libmbdb ahmetmahmodo$ brew link openssl --force
Warning: Refusing to link: openssl
Linking keg-only openssl means you may end up linking against the insecure,
deprecated system OpenSSL while using the headers from Homebrew's openssl.
Instead, pass the full include/library paths to your compiler e.g.:
  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
Ahmet-MacBook:libmbdb ahmetmahmudo$
```

What should i do ?
I  need this command . I reject compile with -I and -L command

Comment: What do you mean? You want to compile and link with `openssl` but you refuse to compile and link with `openssl`?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I want work "brew link openssl --force" command . How do i ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a symlink :

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/{version}/include/openssl /usr/local/include/openssl
```